How to display the specific general term formula of Fibonacci sequence?
RSolve[{a[n] == a[n - 1] + a[n - 2], a[1] == 1, a[2] == 1}, a[n], 
  n] 

The general term formula obtained by the above code is:
{{a[n] -> Fibonacci[n]}}

How can we obtain the following specific general term formula:
1/Sqrt[5] (((1 + Sqrt[5])/2)^n - ((1 - Sqrt[5])/2)^n)


FullSimplify[Fibonacci[n, 1] // FunctionExpand, n ∈ Integers]

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fibonacci.html https://i.sstatic.net/xFzkjTBi.png

Clear["Global`*"];
result = 
 RSolve[{f[n] == f[n - 1] + f[n - 2], f[1] == a, f[2] == b}, f[n], n]
FullSimplify[f[n] /. result[[1]] // FunctionExpand, 
   Assumptions -> n ∈ PositiveIntegers] /. {a -> 1, 
   b -> 1} // Expand



Just another way (here the sequence $a(0)=0,a(1)=1,a(2)=1,...$):
mfn[0] := 0
mfn[n_] := First[MatrixPower[{{1, 1}, {1, 0}}, n - 1] . {1, 0}]
mfn[n]


